# How to extract a substring based on a central element and length added on both sides? Fill X, if the central element is too close to string end

Tags: r, string

I have a string and I would like to extract a substring from it. The way I want to specify substring is

1) by the position of the central element 
2) by the number of elements I want on both sides

E.g. "BBABBB", I would like a substring at position 3 and length of 1 on both sides, which makes "BAB". The tricky part is that if the number of elements is too low I would like to add X. E.g. if I say central position 3 and 3 elements each side, I would like XBBABBB. Is there a function that does it already in R?

Comment: `a=c('BBABBB','12345','SDFGH');substr(a,ceiling(nchar(a)/2)-1,ceiling(nchar(a)/2)+1)`

Comment: @Onyambu  How does this add the required "X"'s ?

Comment: @G5W i only answered the part where he needed the substring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by first padding the string on both ends with enough X's to insure that you will not go past the end of the string,  then extracting the characters that you want with a regular expression.

```
string =  "BBABBB"

position = 3
border   = 4

string2 = capture.output(cat(rep("X", border), string, rep("X", border), sep=""))
Pat = capture.output(cat(".{", position-1, "}(.{", 2*border+1, "}).*", sep=""))
sub(Pat, "\\1", string2)
"XXBBABBBX"
```

Try it with different values of `position` and `border`.

Comment: thanks a lot! A very smart solution. Seems obvious now ))))